# Application crashes when using fragments with activities in Android 2.2

Tags: android, crash, android-asynctask, android-fragments

I am developing an application which does lots of data loading from database so I am using AsyncTasks for the same.

Here is a overall view on what I am creating. I have 2 activities say ActivityA and AcitivityB. ActivityB have number of fragments which load data from database. So I have used different AsyncTask for each fragments which loads data.

Now my issue is that when I press back button of my device while the fragment is getting loaded to go back to ActivityA the application crashes, because ActivityB is no more available. How do I fix this issue?

I am using support libs for Android 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. Just add all the code to a try catch block which will prevent the application to crash even if the activity/fragment throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a big fan of try catch block to swallow exceptions. You are not addressing the root cause.

Here is what i think is happening.

When you press the back button to go back to ActivityA the fragments' views in Activity B are destroyed but the AsyncTask you've started continues to execute and when its done the the AsyncTask's onPostExecute(result) method is called from the UI thread. I'm assuming this where you update your fragments views. But if the views have already been destroyed you get a NullPointerException and that's why its always a good idea to check the fragments' views for null before trying to update them.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to show `ProgressDialog` while process is running in background and make it not cancelable so that when you click back button it will not allow any action. Show the Dialog in `onPreExecute()` and dismiss in `onPostExecute()`. There is no chance of back navigation while loading data in background. You will get updated on UI thread as well as no chance of any exceptions as well as app crashing.